# Writing a function in Python 3 to convert base 16 to base 10

Tags: python-3.x

Is there an easy way to modify this code which converts from base 2 into base 10 to work for converting base 16 into base 10? My objective is to build a dedicated function for conversion and not use any built-in Python features for the calculation. Thanks

```
BinaryVal = int(input('Enter:')
DecVal = 0
for n in range(len(str(BinaryVal))):
    Power = len(str(BinX))-(n+1)
    DecVal += int(str(BinaryVal)[n])*(2**Power)
print(DecVal)
```

Comment: Tell me, how you suppose to avoid the use built-in functions? In your example you used `int()`, `range()`, `len()`, and `str()`. Even you called `int()` in your example, then you refused roippi's answer. Why you want to reinvent wheel, and if you do, why you ask the howto here?

Comment: I meant built in conversion functions like hex() that do the conversions for you. If you want to be rude an debate semantics do it somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Yikes.

`int` already can convert from any base to base 10 - just supply it as the second argument.

```
int('101010',2)
Out[64]: 42

int('2A',16)
Out[66]: 42
```

Comment: My objective is to write a dedicated function rather than use built-in Python features. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: strictly speaking `42` (int object) is not decimal, it is just printed that way. See [`convert_to_decimal_string()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1d523b48efa3/Objects/longobject.c#l1579)

Answer (score 1):

To convert hexadecimal string to `int`:

```
>>> hexstr = '101010'
>>> int(hexstr, 16)
1052688
```

The same -- without `int` constructor:

```
>>> import binascii 
>>> int.from_bytes(binascii.unhexlify(hexstr), 'big')
1052688
```

The same -- similar to [@SzieberthAdam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22626315/4279):

```
>>> hex2dec = {d: i for i, d in enumerate('0123456789abcdef')}
>>> sum(hex2dec[h] * 16**pos for pos, h in enumerate(reversed(hexstr.lower())))
1052688
```

or:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda n, h: n*16 + hex2dec[h], hexstr.lower(), 0)
1052688
```

that is equivalent to:

```
def hex2int(hexstr):
    n = 0
    for h in hexstr.lower():
        n = n*16 + hex2dec[h]
    return n
```

Example:

```
>>> hex2int('101010')
1052688
```

As an alternative, one could convert all digits to `int` first:

```
>>> reduce(lambda n, d: n*16 + d, map(hex2dec.get, hexstr.lower()))
1052688
```

It raises `TypeError` for empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here you go then:

```
>>> binary_num = '101010'
>>> sum(int(b)*2**i for i, b in enumerate(reversed(binary_num)))
42
```

Comment: OP wants to convert base 16 to base 10, not `2`